# Gridview with fixed column widths

Tags: asp.net, html, bootstrap-4

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to have a gridview which has fixed columns width. Right now the columns that have no value are too narrow. This grid is being populated with a datatable on a button click
Could you please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

for BoundField use the property [ItemStyle-Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.itemstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
```